# how exclude the query result from three different tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have 3 tables `offers` `countries` and `transactions` and what I'm trying to do is extract the offers from a specific country and devices, I already do this with this formula:

```
   SELECT
    *
FROM countries a
INNER JOIN offers b ON a.id = b.offer_id
WHERE a.country = "US"
      AND b.device = 'all'
UNION
SELECT
    *
FROM countries a
INNER JOIN offers b ON a.id = b.offer_id
WHERE a.country = "US"
      AND b.device LIKE 'iphone%';
```

This code works but now I want to exclude the offers with the same `ref` between the tables `users` and `transactions`

the way this should work is:

- The user from X country enter on Y device.
- The user select an offer according to his country and device.
- The offer is registered via post back to `transactions`.
- The user enter to the main page and not longer see the offer he already finish.

Right now i'm capable of do the 3 first steps but not the fourth step. Any help about how do this?

Here is an example of the tables: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcaf8b/1)

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

if I put all this on words would be something like:

```
Select all from *offers* where the **offer_id** match with **ID** from *countries* with the **country** "US" and also from *offers* have the **device** "iPhone" now exclude from *transactions* the offers with the **user** = "xxxxx"
```

I hope this explain a little bit what I'm trying to do

Comment: the offers.offer_id is the same id which is stored in transactions.id?
so if somebody accepted a offer and has a transaction, the offer_id is stored in the transactions table?

Comment: how are the tables users & countries linked? so how do you know which country a user is from?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text.

Comment: On a sidenote: Your query should use `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`, because there are no duplicates to detect and remove (device cannot be 'all' and match 'iphone%' at the same time). And anyway, you could easily do this in a single query: `WHERE a.country = 'US' AND (b.device = 'all' OR b.device LIKE 'iphone%')`.

Comment: First thing you should do is get your database straight. You have a country table not containing countries as one would assume, but, erm, offers? At least I see US thrice with IDs that happen to be offer IDs rather than country IDs. The Transaction table, too, contains a column `ID` that again seems not to be a transaction ID, but again an offer ID. Fix your database structure. Only then start writing queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't see how the query is user-specific , but to exclude offers refered to from transactions you can use NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT * 
FROM countries a 
INNER JOIN offers b ON a.id=b.offer_id 
WHERE a.country="US" AND b.device = 'all' 
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM transactions t WHERE t.offer = b.offer_Id)
```

Comment: I ended using your solution with something like this:
`SELECT * 
FROM countries a 
INNER JOIN offers b ON a.offer_id = b.offer_id 
WHERE a.country ='MX' AND (b.device = 'all' OR b.device LIKE 'iPhone%')
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM transactions t WHERE t.oid = b.offer_Id AND t.user = "ab070c5cb6d1a17714661a30d822ea08")`

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to the transactions table.
I added `t.id IS NULL` to the WHERE-clause. So your result will just display offers which have no transaction.

```
          SELECT * 
            FROM countries a 
      INNER JOIN offers b 
              ON a.id = b.offer_id 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions t
              ON t.id = b.offer_id
           WHERE a.country = "US"
             AND t.id IS NULL
```

Regarding your question it is still unclear for me how the tables `users` & `countries` are connected. 
 This is an important detail, as the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` should just grab transactions from this specific user. So the condition `transactions.user = user.ref` should be added to the join too.

Will update the answer whenever you explain me this link

Comment: `users` and `countries` are not connected, countries have the Country ID "US","MX","UK",etc and the `offer ID` when somebody from US enter the query search on the table `countries` for the offer id with `US`

Comment: after that the query search for all the matching offers id from the table `countries` and `offers` like this:
`SELECT 
    *
FROM countries a
INNER JOIN offers b ON a.id = b.offer_id
WHERE a.country = 'MX' AND (b.device = 'all' OR b.device LIKE 'iphone%')`

Comment: when the user end with a offer I receive on the table `transactions` the offer ID and the user ref code that works as ID

Comment: now I need to todo this

`SELECT 
    *
FROM countries a
INNER JOIN offers b ON a.id = b.offer_id
WHERE a.country = 'MX' AND (b.device = 'all' OR b.device LIKE 'iphone%')`

but removing the offer with the ID `415076` as you can see on the example on transactions I have that offer ID there because the user already end with that so I need to exclude that from the query, so at the end on the example you only have the offer with the ID `415807`

Comment: to link the user we use `user` on the table `transactions` and `ref` on the table `users`

Comment: to link the offer with the user we use `user` and `id` from `transactions` being `id` here the same as `offer_id` on `offers`

I know is a mess but the past guy leave everything like this

Comment: @ozonostudio could you update your question and add the desired result? the result you expect with the data in your sqlfiddle.

Comment: as you can see [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcaf8b/10) I use this formula to select what offer was already finish by the user:

`SELECT * FROM cgmr_offers a LEFT OUTER JOIN cgmr_transactions b ON a.offer_id = b.id WHERE b.user = "3TA52R47T"`

I want to do something like that but for exclude this offers from the offers from [this results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcaf8b/9), I'm really new on how exclude rows from the result from other 2 tables